# Rubocop: how can I exclude a filename pattern from a metric?

Tags: rubocop

I want to disable line length checking globally for filenames matching `*_spec.rb` (Serverspec files) in Rubocop.

I tried adding `Exclude` to `config/default.yml` in the following way, but it did not work (no error, offenses detected):

```
Metrics/LineLength:
  Max: 80
  AllowHeredoc: true
  AllowURI: true
  URISchemes:
    - http
    - https
  Exclude:
    - '*_spec.rb'
```

If it is possible, where/how should this be configured?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can match files based on a regular expression by using the `!ruby/regexp` declaration:

```
Metrics/LineLength:
  Max: 80
  AllowHeredoc: true
  AllowURI: true
  URISchemes:
    - http
    - https
  Exclude:
    - !ruby/regexp /_spec\.rb$/
```

RuboCop recently added a [new manual](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/tree/master/manual), and you can read about including and excluding files [here](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/tree/master/manual).

Comment: As far as I know (as an occasional RuboCop committer), we haven't implemented support for using wildcards like that. You could create a feature request for it in the GitHub repo if you want it. :-)

Comment: I see, I took that for granted, I guess, and I was troubleshooting in a different direction.

Comment: If you took it for granted, it probably makes sense for us to add support for it. The actual answer is not very intuitive at all, and requires digging through the manual.